# Difference between "if(TARGET ..." and "if($<TARGET_EXISTS:..."

Tags: cmake

What is the difference between...

```
if(TARGET foo-bar)
  ...
```

and

```
if($<TARGET_EXISTS:foo-bar>)
  ...
```

My belief is that there is no difference.  The value of the generator expression form is that it can be used in other contexts like within a custom_command...  Yes?

Answer (score 3):

**The second version does not work.**

There's no mention of generator expressions in [the documentation of `if`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html) and testing the syntax with both an existing and non-existing targets results in the condition being considered to be false. (Tested on windows with CMake version 3.22.1)

Furthermore if you think about it it does not make sense for generator expressions to work during the configuration: For multi-configuration generators you'd be missing the info about the configuration which could be part of the generator expression. The [debugging suggestions for generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#debugging) also don't mention any way of using the value of a generator expression during the evaluation of the `CMakeLists.txt` files.

#### Difference in context allowing generator expressions

If you're using the generator expression in a context where it's allowed there is a difference: the generator expression is evaluated after cmake is done parsing, `if(TARGET)` just has access to the information available at the time cmake parses the command. If a target is generated after the logic, the generator expression will pick up on the existence of the target, `if(TARGET)` not.

```
if (TARGET MyTarget)
    add_custom_target(Print COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "exists")
else()
    add_custom_target(Print COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "doesn't exist")
endif()

add_custom_target(Print2 COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "$<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:MyTarget>,exists,doesn't exist>")

add_executable(MyTarget ...)
```

The target
`Print` prints `doesn't exist`,
`Print2` prints `exists`

Comment: Thanks @fabian. Your key point is that the first form is evaluated at "configuration" time.  The second form is evaluated at "build" time, after the "if" has been processed away...

Comment: @LanceE.T.Compte It's not really the "build time" when it's evaluated, it't the "generation phase" of the "project setup". E.g. the messages are hardcoded in when generating a Visual Studio solution for the snippet...